# Minimum depth of a d-ary tree of n-elements

Tags: asymptotics, trees

A d-ary tree is a rooted tree in which each node has at most d children

(c) Suppose the tree has n nodes. What is the minimum the depth could possibly be, in terms of n and d? You can leave your answer in big-O format.

---

Solution:
(c) If the tree has n nodes, its depth k must satisfy $n\leq d^{k+1}$, and thus k is $\Omega(log_d n)$.

can someone please walk me through this solution and explain the reasoning behind this problem?

Comment: Do you understand how the solution got $n \leq d^{k+1}$? Understanding that will get you at least started.

Comment: i think i do, $d^k$ is the amount of nodes in level k, and the amount of nodes of that tree would be the summation of $d^k$ from 0 to k, one of the previous questions asked what the maximum number of nodes in a tree (i used the summation here) and that it does not exceed $d^{k+1}$ nodes

Comment: Good. Now take the log (base d) of both sides.

Comment: ok. but wouldn't that give me $k+1 \geq log_dn$ ?? what should i do with the +1 in the first half of the expression?

Comment: Just subtract 1 from both sides. Now you have that $k$ has to be greater than or equal to some expression that includes $d$ and $n$.